# Bootstrap glyphicon symbole not appearing in CakePhp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, cakephp-2.0, carousel

I am trying to implement the right/left arrow using bootstrap `glyphicon` in my `carousel` slider. The project is in `CakePhp`

I needed to implement this :

```
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon` glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
```

So I wrote :

```
<?php
      echo $this->Html->link(
      $this->Html->tag('span', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right')) . "",
      array('controller' => '#myCarousel'),
      array('class' => 'right carousel-control', 'data-slide'=>'next', 'escape' => false)
  );
  ?>
```

But the symbol is not appearing, instead some code appears ! Whats wrong ??

Website Link : [LINK TO WEBSITE](http://fashionlongne.com)

Comment: may be its bootstrap version issue? Which version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: I am using bootstrap `version 3`

Comment: Then you code should work...Well, what code is appearing instead of icon?

Comment: @FazalRasel I edited my question with link to website. Please check

Comment: your `fonts` folder is not there...That why its not working...

Comment: Thanks FazalRasel , uploaded the fonts directory and is working :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer of this question is on comments.. Placing here to make that comments as an answer officially-

Icon is not working because the questioner forget to upload `fonts` folder which contain `bootstrap icons`.